# looking for a video conference solution that supports recording and can be operated from a browser

Tags: jsp, video-capture

I'm looking for a product that can:
1) allows users to have a video conference (picture + sound)
2) can be embedded in a jsp web page
3) supports video recording which can also be operated from the browser

The product may be commercial (or open source).

Thanks,
Yael

Comment: -20. Not programming related.

Comment: I thought of that, but I think the embedded requirment makes it a programming question as I need something with some API to write code around.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the direction that you want to take but I know that flash has Great libraries to do this.  It is even easy to do with very minimal programming.  It is also very easy to do streaming, live streaming, recording etc.  Look into the "app-server".  Works pretty well.  The tutorials that come with flash are also great they will walk you right through setting something like that up.

Flash is built on actionscript which bears a very close resemblance to java.  Should be pretty easy to pick up.

Comment: The problem is that I already have a java-jsp client-server application and I want to add video conference abilities between users.

Comment: Flash is just something you *embed* in a page. Like Javascript or Java applet. That's exactly what you're looking for. On the server side just have a servlet which processes the streams.